# Sort multidimensional array with tricky conditions

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm a new to php. I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array with some conditions but I have no idea where to start.

Users array

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [Fname] => Kcir
            [Lname] => Nayr
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 45
            [totalScore] => 26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [Fname] => Doe
            [Lname] => John
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 35
            [totalScore] => 26
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 3
            [Fname] => Greg
            [Lname] => Cuenca
            [Nickname] => Greg
            [wins] => 11
            [scoreGuess] => 21
            [totalScore] => 26
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 4
            [Fname] => Kenneth
            [Lname] => Agee
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 34
            [totalScore] => 26
        )
)
```

First, I need to sort users via **wins** in descending order and then if there are users that are tied in **wins** then the tied users will be sort via **scoreGuess** but there is a condition. If the **scoreGuess** is the closest on the **totalScore** then that user will be the top.

E.g.: User **1**, **2** , and **3** are tied in wins **12** and the totalScore is **26**.
**User 1** has a scoreGuess of **45**
**User 2** has a scoreGuess of **35**
**User 4** has a scoreGuess of **34**

So the one will be top is **User 4** since he has the closest scoreGuess.

I've tried this code but is not working.

```php
function compareUsers($a, $b)
{
            if($a['wins'] > $b['wins'])
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if ($a['wins'] == $b['wins']) {
                $a_diff = (int) $a['totalScore'] - (int)$a['scoreGuess'];
                $b_diff = (int) $b['totalScore'] - (int) $b['scoreGuess'];

                if ( $a_diff >= 0 && $b_diff >= 0 ) {
                    if ( $a_diff < $b_diff ) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                } else if ( $a_diff >= 0 && $b_diff < 0 ) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
}

usort($users, "compareUsers");
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [Fname] => Kcir
            [Lname] => Nayr
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 45
            [totalScore] => 26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [Fname] => Doe
            [Lname] => John
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 35
            [totalScore] => 26
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 4
            [Fname] => Kenneth
            [Lname] => Agee
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 34
            [totalScore] => 26
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 3
            [Fname] => Greg
            [Lname] => Cuenca
            [Nickname] => Greg
            [wins] => 11
            [scoreGuess] => 21
            [totalScore] => 26
        )
)
```

Comment: A starting point could be [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: unable to understand as well as unable to see `User 1 has a scoreGuess of 20
User 2 has a scoreGuess of 24
User 3 has a scoreGuess of 30`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Ok my bad. I edited my post.

Comment: @Kboyz  please add your code attempt what you have tried so far....

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Okay I've added my code attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you could keep it more simple like below:

```
usort($arr,function($data1,$data2){
    if($data1['wins'] != $data2['wins']) return -1 * ($data1['wins'] - $data2['wins']);
    return abs($data1['scoreGuess'] - $data1['totalScore']) - abs($data2['scoreGuess'] - $data2['totalScore']);
});
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/KCuf9

- We see if `wins` of set is equal or not with other set's `wins`.
- If they aren't equal, we return the difference of both multiplied by `-1` for descending order.
- if they are equal, we take the difference of absolute values of difference between `scoreGuess` and `totalScore`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following solution using `usort`, sorting by wins when the number of wins is different. When the number of wins is equal, the sorting is done with the difference between totalScore and scoreGuess.

```
$array = [
    0 => [    
        'uid' => 1,
        'Fname' => 'Kcir',
        'Lname' => 'Nayr',
        'wins' => 12,
        'scoreGuess' => 45,
        'totalScore' => 26,
    ],
    1 => [
        'uid' => 2,
        'Fname' => 'Doe',
        'Lname' => 'John',
        'wins' => 12,
        'scoreGuess' => 35,
        'totalScore' => 26,
    ],
    2 => [
        'uid' => 3,
        'Fname' => 'Greg',
        'Lname' => 'Cuenca',
        'Nickname' => 'Greg',
        'wins' => 11,
        'scoreGuess' => 21,
        'totalScore' => 26,
    ],
    3 => [
        'uid' => 4,
        'Fname' => 'Kenneth',
        'Lname' => 'Agee',
        'wins' => 12,
        'scoreGuess' => 34,
        'totalScore' => 26,
    ],
];

usort($array, function($prev, $next) {
     if ($next['wins'] == $prev['wins']) {
          return abs($prev['scoreGuess'] - $prev['totalScore']) <=> abs($next['scoreGuess'] - $next['totalScore']);
     } else {
          return $next['wins'] <=> $prev['wins'];
     }
});
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 4
            [Fname] => Kenneth
            [Lname] => Agee
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 34
            [totalScore] => 26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [Fname] => Doe
            [Lname] => John
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 35
            [totalScore] => 26
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [Fname] => Kcir
            [Lname] => Nayr
            [wins] => 12
            [scoreGuess] => 45
            [totalScore] => 26
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 3
            [Fname] => Greg
            [Lname] => Cuenca
            [Nickname] => Greg
            [wins] => 11
            [scoreGuess] => 21
            [totalScore] => 26
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1746ddb6847c577a958af8e6dfcb3753bd750a20)